# Create and open file with one command?

Tags: command-line, files

I want to create a text file and open it in a text editor with a single command.

I know `touch file.txt` creates a file and `open file.txt` opens the file, but is there a way to do this with a single command?

Comment: Which text editor gives you difficulty? Is there an error message? The editors with which I am acquainted (`ed`,`nano`,`vi`,`vim`,`emacs`,`teco`,`LibreOffice`, ...) all regard a non-existent file as empty, and create the file upon exit (or when one writes the buffer). If your editor doesn't do that, it may be a bug.

Comment: Of note, I believe this is rather unique to MacOS; Linux does not have an `open(1)` man page, nor is it recognized as a command in Linux.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `touch myfile.txt; open myfile.txt`. If this is something you'll be doing frequently, you could create an alias for it.

Comment: How would you use an alias to create a file, and then open it? I don't think that would be the most robust (if even possible) way of handling this. If so, an example would definitely be awesome for people to see.

Comment: `alias touch_open='touch myfile.txt; open myfile.txt'` would work to create the Alias. Alternatively, could write a small function that would take in a parameter, ie. `function touch_open { touch "$@"; open "$@"; }` and then run that as `touch_open myfile.txt`

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for some logic for this, ie. create a file and open if possible you could use something like this:

```
touch testFile && vi testFile
```

Here testFile is created with touch. The `&&` part says if the creation was successful then open it with vi.

Also, you could just create a new file with something like vi, while opening it at the same time (this assumes you save the file after editing it).

```
vi testFile
```

Answer (score 4):

That entirely depends on your text editor. Most will allow you to simply open a non-existent file, and assume you want it created on save.

You could also use a function if that is somehow not possible for you:

```
cropen() {
    if ! [ "$1" ]; then
        echo "need a file!" >&2
        return 1
    fi
    : > "$1" && open "$1"
}
```

You can call it as `cropen file`.

Answer (score 3):

Use vim. Just type

```
vim newfile.txt
```

For vim you need to know the [hot-keys](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html).

```
i   - Insert text in the file
esc - return to the command-input-mode
:w  - Write (save)
:q  - Quit (exit)
```

or (Easier to use `Nano`):

```
nano newfile.txt
```

If you want a GUI type: (Works for ubuntu and other distros)

```
gedit newfile.txt
```

Comment: I'd rather `:wq` or even `:x` to save and exit :)

Comment: @Bernhard of corse! thats better... those options are to be mixed as you like =)

Answer (score 2):

Like everyone is telling you, this depends on your editor. And if you don't like the way your editor handles this, that can probably be configured, as well.

With Emacs, `emacs new_file.txt` (for a nonexistent `new_file.txt` in the current directory) will bring up Emacs and display a buffer that refers to a `new_file.txt`. However, until you **save**, there will be no such file. If you don't do anything and quit, no file will have been created.

While this is certainly one way, I think an even better way is to always have an instance of Emacs running. So, whenever you feel the need for a new file, go to Emacs, hit `C-x C-f` (or `M-x find-file RET`), then write the path to the nonexistent file, and you're at the same point as after the CLI command (above, in the second paragraph).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use: `>> 001.c && vim $_`

Answer (score 1):

Creates file && opens file.

```
touch fileName.txt && vim $_
```